Paypal show Error - order not created when customer attempts purchase
I am using WP Express Checkout on a WP website for digital purchases using Paypal. Purchases have been unsuccessful recently and show the error
Could not initiate PayPal Checkout...
Failed to create the order using PayPal API. Enable the debug logging feature to get more details.
I cannot see how to enable Debug logging to investigate further. How do I do this?

Enable WP_DEBUG = true in wp-config.php file to check the error.
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

Add this code in functions.php file for SSL certificate problem:
add_filter('http_request_args', function ($args) {
    $args['sslverify'] = false;
    return $args;
}, 10, 1);


Enabling debugging in WP Express Checkout plug-in and viewing log showed error to be 2024-12-26 22:41:08: [SUCCESS] Error creating PayPal order: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate. However, no success in dealing with this problem

Your domain doesn't have an SSL certificate?

Check the updated answer

There are many functions.php files in inetpub - in wp-content/themes and wp-content/plugins. Do they all need updating

There is no functions.php  file in wp-content/plugins/wp-express-checkout which is the plugin I am using for Paypal purchases

The domain does have an SSL certificate

You need to add this code to your active theme functions.php file

Using TwentySixteen theme. Added code to functions.php in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AlekaConsulting\AlekaConsulting\wp-content\themes\twentysixteen. Same error - Error creating PayPal order: error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\cacert.pem CApath: none

Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Have defined curl.cainfo="C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\cacert.pem"; as suggested in php.ini

download cacert.pem and upload in locations: CAfile: C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\cacert.pem https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

cacert.pem was obtained from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html

success! I was adding cacert.pem in C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\certs\cacert.pem

working fine?..

Yes - thanks for your help
